# Phoneme generation Tools

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, speech, htk

I recently came across Logios Lexicon Tool (http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lextool.html), which allows you to input a word and generate a phoneme for it (even if the words doesn't exist in the current dictionary).

I was wondering if there are similar tools that exist aside from it?

Comment: It is not a good idea to ask for recommendation on SO. There are tools of course like phonetisaurus or sequitur, you can find links here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialdict

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Sorry about that. Don't know where else ask. Thanks as well for referring me to the link.

Comment: You are welcome to ask on CMUSphinx forum!